# SQL query between two values in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 x tables. I'm trying to select values that match the criteria in 2nd table. I am not sure about the JOINS and also how to 'exclude' codes in range between  Tbl2.code3excfrom and Tbl2.code3excto

So, SQL Query will be something like

```
SELECT Tbl2.code, Tbl1.compcode, Tbl1.value  
FROM Tbl1 CROSS JOIN Tbl2  
WHERE Tbl1.compcode = 'ABC1' AND (Tbl2.code2incfrom >= Tbl1.code2 AND
Tbl1.code2 <= Tbl2.code2incto) AND (Tbl2.code3incfrom >= Tbl1.code3 AND
Tbl1.code3 <= Tbl2.code3incto) AND NOT (Tbl2.code3excfrom >= Tbl1.code3
AND Tbl1.code3 <= Tbl2.code3excto)
```

Tbl1

```
compcode    code1   code2   code3   code4   value  
-------------------------------------------------
ABC1        CAD     110     11018   FA1199  £3,128.16  
ABC1        CAD     115     11518   BABOA1  £92.00  
ABC1        CAD     230     23010   ZX123   £150.00  
ABC1        CAD     400     40100   CA45    £456.00  
ABC1        CAD     600     60018   DA1199  £1,548.00
```

Tbl2

```
code    compincfrom compincto   code2incfrom    code2incto  code3incfrom    code3incto  code3excfrom    code3excto  code4incfrom    code4incto  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
LINE_01     AA      EZ99999     110             110             *           *           NULL            NULL            *           *  
LINE_02     AA      EZ99999     115             115             11500       11519       NULL            NULL            BA          ZZZZZZZZZ  
LINE_03     AA      EZ99999     230             230             23000       23099       23010           23015           *           *  
LINE_04     AA      EZ99999     400             400             40000       40100       NULL            NULL            BA          ZZZZZZZZZ  
LINE_05     AA      EZ99999     600             600             *           *           60102           60103           BA          ZZZZZZZZZ
```

Result

```
code    compcode    value  
--------------------------------
LINE_01     ABC1    £3,128.16  
LINE_02     ABC1    £92.00  
LINE_04     ABC1    £456.00  
LINE_05     ABC1    £1,548.00
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Can you show me your temporary table’s data and expected output?

Comment: I tried to upload pic but I don't have enough reputation points. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Oh my... Please edit those to the original post in proper format, preferably insert into clauses.

Comment: Also, is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks JamesZ how do I insert into clauses? It's SQL Server.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. I think you're going to have problems with some of those null values though.

Comment: Yup and also the code are text so problems with the "*" too Thanks shawn!

Comment: Keep the table structure code as source code formatted(Select and Ctrl+K) so the code will look same as it is.

Comment: What does `*` and `NULL` mean here?

Comment: Hi Giorgi  
* means return everything 
NULL means nothing in the that field. Field is blank
The data type is varchar

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.`code`, T1.`compcode`, T1.`value`  
FROM table1Name T1 CROSS JOIN table2Name T2
ON T1.`compcode` = 'ABC1' 
AND (T2.`code2incfrom` >= T1.`code2` AND T1.`code2` <= T2.`code2incto`)
AND (T2.`code3incfrom` >= T1.`code3` AND T1.`code3` <= T2.`code3incto`)
AND NOT (T2.`code3excfrom` >= T1.`code3` AND T1.`code3` <= T2.`code3excto`)
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket! Have a problem in that the codes are text so nothing is returned where there are "*" in the ranges

Comment: I just rearranged your answer, now analysing

Comment: Thanks SO much for helping with the edit Rocket, may I ask how you did it so I know for future! Thanks again!

Comment: Are you using PHP+MySQL?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server Mgnt Studio (SQL Query) does that answer your Q ?

Comment: Add a NULL condition check and then your problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

I changed your data a bit (* -> NULL) so that the data type can be int instead of varchar, but this should work:

```
SELECT
    Tbl2.code, 
    Tbl1.compcode, 
    Tbl1.value
FROM 
    Tbl1 
    CROSS JOIN Tbl2  
WHERE 
    Tbl1.compcode = 'ABC1' AND 
    Tbl2.code2incfrom <= Tbl1.code2 AND 
    Tbl1.code2 <= Tbl2.code2incto AND 
    case when Tbl2.code3incfrom is NULL then -1 else Tbl2.code3incfrom end 
        <= Tbl1.code3 AND 
    Tbl1.code3 <= 
        case when Tbl2.code3incto is NULL then 99999 else Tbl2.code3incto end AND
    NOT (
        case when Tbl2.code3excfrom is NULL then 99999 else Tbl2.code3excfrom end <= 
            Tbl1.code3 AND
        Tbl1.code3 <= 
            case when Tbl2.code3excto is NULL then -1 else Tbl2.code3excto end
    )
```

You had some issues with < vs > and the check for * (=now NULL) was missing. Also this misses the last criteria (code4incfrom / code4incto) but that wasn't in your SQL.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3bed/5

Comment: Getting an error
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '*' to data type int."

Comment: Like I said, I changed your DATA so that it wouldn't have numbers stored as text because that can cause accidental problems with greater than / less than comparison. If you really want to have * which I do not recommend, replace the is NULL with = '*' and add convert int to the columns

Comment: And by changing * into NULL, it would have also been the same way as the next columns, which have NULL instead of *

Comment: Thanks JamesZ trying various things in my qry

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM  (
SELECT 
  Tbl2.code,
  Tbl1.compcode,
  Tbl1.value 
FROM  Tbl1 CROSS JOIN Tbl2  ON  Tbl1.compcode = 'ABC1' AND (Tbl1.code2 <= Tbl2.code2incfrom AND Tbl1.code2 <= Tbl2.code2incto )
 AND (Tbl1.code3 <= Tbl2.code3incfrom AND Tbl1.code3 <= Tbl2.code3incto )
 AND NOT (Tbl1.code3 <= Tbl2.code3excfrom   AND Tbl1.code3 <= Tbl2.code3excto )

 ) temp WHERE temp.compcode='ABC1';
```

Answer (score 0):

reusing jamesZ [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09e27/6) :

```
WITH fltr AS (
   SELECT code
       , code2incfrom = CASE WHEN code2incfrom='*' THEN -1    ELSE code2incfrom END
       , code2incto   = CASE WHEN code2incto  ='*' THEN 99999 ELSE code2incto END
       , code3incfrom = CASE WHEN code3incfrom='*' THEN -1    ELSE code3incfrom END
       , code3incto   = CASE WHEN code3incto  ='*' THEN 99999 ELSE code3incto END
   FROM tbl2   
)

SELECT Tbl1.*, fltr.*
FROM Tbl1 
LEFT JOIN fltr 
  ON  tbl1.code2 BETWEEN fltr.code2incfrom AND code2incTo 
  AND tbl1.code3 BETWEEN fltr.code3incfrom AND code3incTo
WHERE tbl1.compcode = 'ABC1'
```